# C# Serialize class into byte[] that is not marked as Serializable

Tags: c#, serialization, binary-serialization

I have classes like below and **which I cannot change** since these are almost 20+ years old classes and they are already in production used by many applications. **This is maintained by a team and before I go to them and ask to make change which I feel will be big change I need to make sure that I explore all the options.**

```
[Serializable]
public class MyDTO
{
  public string FullName {get;set;}
  public List<Address> Addresses {get;set}
}

// Note: It is not marked as Serializable
public class Address
{
  public string FullAddress {get;set;}
  
}
```

I am creating MyDTO like below

```
List<Address> myAddresses = new List<Address>()
{
   new Address() { FullAddress =" FullAddress1"},
   new Address() { FullAddress =" FullAddress2"}
}

MyDTO dto = new MyDTO() 
{
  FullName = "FullName",
  Addresses = myAddresses
}
```

**Now I am trying to convert dto in byte[] like below.**

```
public byte[] SerializeToByteArray(MyDTO dto)
{
  byte[] byteArray = null;
  BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    bf.Serialize(ms, dto);
    byteArray = ms.ToArray();
  }
  return byteArray;
}
```

I am getting exception as
**Type 'xxx.Address' in Assembly 'xxx.yyy.zzz, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.**

Can anybody please tell me how we can solve this issue without making Address as Serializable.
I need to convert dto  into byte[]

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**

I tried what @Neil suggested in comments and now my initial problem is solved ( I assume ) but I get new problem so I feel what I am doing is wrong.

This is what I am doing now

```
public byte[] SerializeToByteArray<T>(T dto)
{
 byte[] byteArray = null;
 BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
 {
   bf.Serialize(ms, dto);
   byteArray = ms.ToArray()
 }
 return byteArray;
}
string jsonString = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto);
byte[] byteArray = SerializeToByteArray(jsonString);
string dtoByteArrayBase64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

I send dtoByteArrayBase64String to server side and I am receiving it.
On server I try to re-create MyDTO object like below

```
byte[] inputDTOByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(dtoByteArrayBase64String);
MyDTO  myDTO = DeserializeFromByteArray<MyDTO>(inputDTOByteArray);

public T DeserializeFromByteArray<T>(byte[] byteArray)
{
  T dto;
  BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
  {
    object obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
    dto = (T)obj; // getting error here
  }
  return dto;
}
```

I am getting below error
**Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'MyDTO'.**

Comment: question: are you *restricted* to `BinaryFormatter`; there are other serializers that might be able to work here, but that isn't worth discussing if you really mean "with `BinaryFormatter`"; if you mean "with `BinaryFormatter`", the only option I can think of is "surrogates"

Comment: @MarcGravell... SerializeToByteArray is my method and I can use any formatter unless I get it reviewed by security team and it works.What you mean by surrogates?

Comment: here's a walkthrough of surrogates - it is for pretty much exactly this scenario: https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/14386/serialization-surrogates--implementing-iserializationsurrogate- - and as for other serializers: I'm biased, so I was thinking of protobuf-net :)

Comment: Can you serialise to json and then serialize to byte[] ?

Comment: @MarcGravell.. I will look into it...

Comment: @Neil... as I am typing this I am trying it. My first try was to convert directly...

Answer (score 2):

If you are tied to `BinaryFormatter`, the feature you're looking for is "surrogates"; this isn't a small topic, so it is hard to give a concise example, but a full walkthrough is covered [here](https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/14386/serialization-surrogates--implementing-iserializationsurrogate-); essentially, a surrogate is a custom type that gets used internally *instead of* the type it encounters, so your custom type can do all the extra logic required.

However! In general, `BinaryFormatter` should be considered legacy and obsolete. Nobody is taking it away from you, and it is going to keep working (on .NET Framework, at least), but: if possible, you should consider looking at alternative options. For some of the reasons: [see here](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/03/why-do-i-rag-on-binaryformatter.html)